# How does one add multiple rows to an array list in java?

Tags: java

I have a String[] (a string array) that has multiple values at its different indexes. Now I want to add this complete array of strings to a single index of an array list (ArrayList).

Comment: What problem you are facing? Just add it.

Comment: The ArrayList wasn't storing all the entered data. It was saving info just on one index and then over riding the inputs onwards.

Comment: It's working fine now. I have initialised the array list just before the main so it doesn't get initialised every time an input is saved. Thank You @Kartic though.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
List<String[]> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
stringArrayList.add(/*your String[]*/);
```

A complete example:

```
package nl.testing.startingpoint;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] stringArrayOne = {"one", "two"};
        String[] stringArrayTwo = {"three", "four"};

        List<String[]> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        stringArrayList .add(stringArrayOne);
        stringArrayList .add(stringArrayTwo);

        for (String[] objectArray : stringArrayList) {
            for (String object : objectArray) {
                System.out.println(object);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

- one
- two
- three
- four

This is called using [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html). Check the link for more generics example!

Comment: Thank you @Igoranze sir. It got my code working to quite an extent.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the Map or LinkedHashMap> to store the data in particular order

Comment: I don't think your answer is relevant to the question.